# How to hide line numbers on Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I want to copy a small chunk of code from Gerrit, but the line numbers are getting copied too. Is there any way to get rid of these line numbers?

Comment: a text-editor with regex search-replace should help you achieve this in a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATE for IE: install a page-css-editing plugin like the "Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar" (or whatever) and add the property `display: none` to the CSS element `.CodeMirror-linenumber` . (see: https://superuser.com/questions/286184/how-do-you-edit-css-in-ie-developer-tools for details how to do that)*

You can go to the diff view and copy the code from there - it should allow selecting without the lines. (You can also download the file from there).

If not, where exactly in Gerrit are you copying from (and on what browser)?

Comment: I am using IE. The diff view has line numbers for both sides

Answer (score 0):

Open up inspect element on your browser and set this CSS propery for the *ol* element:

`list-style-type: none;`